# unordered_map<string, vector<string>> - memory location changes when things are push_back

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, unordered-map

I have this code here. It's a weird unordered_map of `string` to `vector<string>`. Why does the memory location of the older strings change with each `push_back` to the vector?

The I tried the same thing on an `unordered_map<string, vector<int>>`, and the memory locations of the ints in the vector of ints did *NOT* exhibit the same behavior, i.e. with each push_back, the older ints did not change their memory location. I originally though it's because ints are smaller than strings memory-wise, but pushing back 50 ints still do not change the memory location. Why is there such a difference?

This is compiled on a MacOS, with the clang version of Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31). This happens regardless if I compile with the c++11 flag or not.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, vector<string> > kvStore;
    kvStore["a"] = vector<string>();
    cout << "kvStore mem location: " << &(kvStore) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"]) << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "--1st push_back--" << endl;
    kvStore["a"].push_back("foo");
    cout << "kvStore mem location: " << &(kvStore) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"]) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a][0] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"][0]) << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "--2nd push_back--" << endl;
    kvStore["a"].push_back("bar");
    cout << "kvStore mem location: " << &(kvStore) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"]) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a][0] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"][0]) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a][1] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"][1]) << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "--3rd push_back--" << endl;
    kvStore["a"].push_back("foobar");
    cout << "kvStore mem location: " << &(kvStore) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"]) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a][0] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"][0]) << endl;
    cout << "kvStore[a][1] mem location: " << &(kvStore["a"][1]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because that is how `vector`s work. If you `push_back` and the capacity of the vector needs to be increased it allocates a new array (internally) and copies all elements to that new array before adding the item.

Comment: It also happens with `int`s because that is, how others have explained, how `std::vector` works. As a matter of fact, I tried your code example on my machine with `std::vector<int>`, and got different memory locations. Please provide an example where 50 `push_back`s on a `std::vector<int>` do not cause contents to be moved around.

Comment: @ChristianHackl hmm I will try again - maybe the `vector<int>` example was a coincidence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) all iterators and references to `vector`'s elements are invalidated if the new `size()` > `capacity()`. To avoid this, call [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) first.

For example, replace

```
kvStore["a"] = vector<string>();
```

with

```
kvStore["a"].reserve(3);
```

(`map`'s `operator[]` creates a zero-initialized element if the key doesn't exist, so the explicit assignment is superfluous)

and adresses won't change. [live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kvJUr2TRO0VoZQ7T)